# Multiple instance of jquery and sending value to php via ajax

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am having an issue with with multiple instances of jquery and the way its taking data and sends it to next step via ajax.

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {

    $('#toggle'+i).change(function(i){
      var mode= $(this).prop('checked');
      var data+i = $('#building_'+i).val();
      // // submit the form 
      // $(#myForm).ajaxSubmit(); 
      // // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
      // return false; 
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      dataType:'JSON',
      url:'admin/sites/audio_alarm.php',
      data: { mode: mode, building_id: data+i },
      success:function(data)
      {
        var data=eval(data);
        message=data.message;
        success=data.success;
        $("#heading").html(success);
        $("#body").html(message);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

then i have a list of buildings from database:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle<?php echo $row["id"];?>" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled">
<input type="hidden" name = "building_id_<?php echo $row["id"];?>" id="building_id_<?php echo $row["id"];?>" value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
```

at the moment this doesn't work. If i remove all the IDs from the latter code it will work but only sending the first instance (in this case id of 1).

Basically what this does is, there is a list of building. Each result has a toggle switch to disable the building. Once you toggle the switch I need it to send the building ID through ajax and update the DB.

I have looked around but find similar issue. Also, iam a newbie to jquery and it seem s too complicated for me at the moment.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT:

Just if anyone is interested:

The below marked answer works and as suggested i am passing the value in one element (checkbox)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
```

Comment: `data+i` is not a valid variable name. `+` is an operator, it can't be part of an identifier.

Comment: You should have gotten a syntax error from the JavaScript, and it shouldn't run at all.

Comment: `$('#building_'+i)` should be `$('#building_id_'+i)`

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple instances of jQuery"? If you're loading multiple versions of jQuery you need to use `jQuery.noConflict()` to keep them from interfering with each other.

Comment: Why is the value of `building_id_X` just the value of `X`? What's the point of that?

Comment: Why are you using `eval(data)`? jQuery automatically parses the JSON, you don't need to evaluate it (and the safe way to do that would be with `JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all the checkboxes and hidden inputs a class, so you can select that rather than looping over the ID numbers.

Then use a DOM traversal function to find the hidden input after it, which I've also given a class.

Use a valid variable name (`data+i` is not valid), and don't call `eval(data)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').change(function(i) {
    var mode = $(this).prop('checked');
    var data = $(this).next('.building').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url: 'admin/sites/audio_alarm.php',
      data: {
        mode: mode,
        building_id: data
      },
      success: function(data) {
        message = data.message;
        success = data.success;
        $("#heading").html(success);
        $("#body").html(message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" class="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled">
<input type="hidden" name = "building_id_<?php echo $row["id"];?>" class="building" value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. It looks like that data variable is not being passed through. All i get is "undefined"

Comment: Is the hidden input really right after the checkbox, as you show?

Comment: And you added `class="building"` to the hidden input?

Comment: yes i have copied exactly what you have replied :-)

Comment: You could also put the data in the value of the checkbox itself, instead of using a separate hidden input. Than you can do `var data = $(this).val();`